# C# program to Print whole table from oracle database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, oracle12c

There are many tables in hr.
I want to write a program to allow user to enter table name and I have to print all the data from table to console.

The problem is that for all the tables the structure is different. I mean there are different attributes in different tables. How can I print all the data from a particular table?

I wrote the following code. How to print all table data?

```
using System;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

namespace Ass1Que1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
               string constr = "DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/orclpdb;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=HR;password=hr";
                string table = "";
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle Database {0}", con.ServerVersion);
                // con.Dispose();
                Console.Write("Enter the table name: ");
                table = Console.ReadLine();
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("" + reader.GetString(0));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}", ex);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code is working fine for me but I just want to print all the data means I want to print output of `Select *`. And It should be applicable for all tables.

Comment: code looks good, but you might want to edit out any usernames and passwords even if you are just running on your local machine. What's not working?

Comment: It is working fine. I just want to print all the data means I want to print output of Select *. And It should be applicable for all tables

Comment: You can get a count of the columns in the table, and for each row returned loop through the columns to print the values.

Comment: But there are different data types in different table. So how can I parse them? Can you pls suggest a code

Comment: You're using Console.WriteLine, so you don't need to worry about the data types.

Comment: @Tim Can you please provide a code to get a count of columns in table. I am totally new to C#

Comment: I don't have oracle running on my pc so I can't test - is `reader.GetString(0)` only displaying the first row or something like that?

Comment: @S_Madankar - Just use the `FieldCount` property on the reader, before you enter the `while` loop.  Something like `var cols = reader.FieldCount;` after you execute the reader and before the `while` loop should do.  Then inside the while loop do a for loop to go through each column in that row and print it out.

Comment: If you are wanting to print `SELECT *` the problem is you are only printing the first column with `reader.GetString(0)`. What do you want your output to be?

Comment: @user1274820 No It is just printing first column value

Comment: @npearson I want to print all the columns. reader.GetString(0) is wrong statement there

Comment: Try `reader.GetValue(i);`, where i is the column you're on in the for loop.   Since you're using Console.WriteLine, it'll handle the different data types being passed into it before writing to the console.

Comment: @Tim That helps... Thank you

Comment: @Tim should just post that as the correct answer.  If you want to write each column from the reader just loop through each row using `reader.GetValue(i)`

Comment: @Tim "npearson" is right. you should post that correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a trivial example based on my comments.  Note that it's not tested, but the theory is based on the similar `SqlDataReader`.   The snippet below will print both the column name and the value (theoretically at least):

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var cols = reader.FieldCount;

while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

You might be able to do `Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);` as well - you could do that with a `SqlDataReader`, but I'm not 100% sure with `OracleDataReader`.